# Angular JS - 10 $Digest cycles error for strings?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-digest, ng-style

Please refer the console while you run - http://jsfiddle.net/E9bU5/239/

```
$scope.changecolor = function() {
    return colorlist[($scope.j++)%colorlist.length]; //Returns a string, not an object.
};
```

From other SO posts, I understand that this error is thrown when the result is an object and different all the time. But in my case it is just string. Then also it is throwing the error. How to fix this?

Comment: just dont put counter variable on scope? use j instead of $scope.j?

Comment: @YOU - Ohk, that's fine. But that doesn't stop the Digest errors!

Comment: ah, you shouldn't call function() inside angular expressions, it will run many times until changes stop.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? different colors for each numbers?

Comment: @YOU - Yes, diff color for each number. 2 Questions then. Other than function inside the expression, what else? Second, it's returning a string and not an object. So this error should not occur, right?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/S_YOU/E9bU5/240/ - if you pass $index, each function run will be same result for each item.

Comment: no, object or string does not matter, if the same expression run more than limit, it will throw error to prevent infinite loop.

Comment: @YOU - YOU the man!!!

Comment: It works :) thanks...!

Comment: @YOU - But I did not get the $index thingy. Could you pls elaborate.

Comment: its loop(ng-repeat) index, automatically injected by angular - $index, $first $last $middle $odd $even are there too, imo.